# How to use Meteor JS Node server to proxy a 3rd party ajax request

Tags: javascript, meteor, http-proxy

I have a 3rd party JSON endpoint which does not support CORS, I have been in formed my application should proxy the request through the server. I have researched this for a few hours today and am not seeing a simple solution (a couple complex ones...).

So basically I need to do something like `request( 'http://localhost:3000/publications/jsonProxy' )`, which calls the Meteor server. Then I need a publication that requests data from the 3rd party with a secure token, and I need to return that data to the browser.

I've attempted something like:

```
const request = require('request');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('jsonProxy', function jsonProxyPublication() {
    var options = {
      url: 'https://somewhere.com/api/endpoint',
      headers: {
        'API-Key': '123'
      }
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(info);
        return info
      } else {
        console.error( error, response )
      }
    }

    request(options, callback);

    return this.ready()
  });
}
```

Then: `curl localhost:3000/publications/jsonProxy`. This may not be close to the correct way to do this, I'm kind of lost.

Seems simple enough, can anyone point me the right way to get this data back to the browser?

Comment: Update - I figured it out and will post shortly

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I got it working. Example code below, not "real" code as I had to extract it out of context.

**/server/proxy/json-api.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'

Meteor.methods( {
  'jsonProxy' () {
    const apiUrl = 'https://api.com/api'

    const response = HTTP.get( apiUrl, {
      headers: {
        'API-Key': '123'
      }
    } ).data

    console.log( `${ apiUrl } response:`, response )

    return response
  }
} )
```

**/server/main.js**

```
import './proxy/jsonodds.js'
```

**/imports/ui/pages/app/app.js**

```
Meteor.call( 'jsonProxy', ( error, result ) => {
  if( !error ) {
    Session.set( 'jsonData', result )

  } else {
    Session.set( 'jsonData', `Error: ${ JSON.stringify( error ) } `)
  }
}  )

Template.app.helpers( {
  jsonData() {
    return Session.get( 'jsonData' )
  }
} )
```

**/imports/ui/pages/app/app.html**

```
<template name="app">
  <div id="app">
    {{#each jsonData}}
      {{> itemTemplate}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="itemTemplate">
  <p>{{displayName}}</p>
</template>
```

Edit: I'm not sure if it matters the proxy is in the `server` folder, but hey it's working and I have more things to build.

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45957165/1177832) using the `WebApp` module to define server routes is much cleaner.